# how to pass an array to bar chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have drawn charts using morris.js which is pretty easy, but I want to switch to charts.js library. I have an array which has 'date' and two other values, I want to plot the date values on x-axis and the rest two on y-axis using chart.js bar function.

In morris it was easy to define values separately for both the axis but I don't understand how to do this in chart.js.

```
 function testChart(myArray){ 

new Chart(document.getElementById("churn-bar-chart"), {
type: 'bar',
myArray: {
  labels: 'date',
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850"],
      data: ['new', 'lost']
    }
  ]
},
options: {
  legend: { display: true },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
  }
}
  });
  }

 // myArray
  var UserArray = new Array();
  UserArray= [];

  var obj2 = {};
                obj2.date = Date;
                obj2.new = newUser;
                obj2.lost =  lostUser;
                UserArray.push(obj2);
```

Comment: Chart.js works differently than morris. Don't confuse the two. Look at how data is being passed in this example: view-source:http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html

Comment: there is no sample code on this link.

Comment: view page source...

Comment: How's your array (`myArray`) looks like ??

Comment: @ɢʀᴜɴᴛ please check the updated post.